# My iPhone SE (a1723) doesn't pick up 4G signal, only EDGE

Tags: iphone, ios, network

I bought an used iPhone SE here in Brazil (model A1723) but it doesn't pick up any network faster than EDGE, I can make phone calls and browse the network in slow speeds.

In settings I can see that 4G is active, I've already tried resetting the network settings but no luck, any thoughts?

Comment: I'd start by ringing your provider, see if you might need a new SIM or if they need to set something up from their end, new provisioning profile etc.

Comment: It was a provider's issue, thanks for the comment! :)